# Only one instance of Thread in service

Tags: android

I initialize new Thread in service but when i start service the new one is made and it make my app crash beacause I use camera in it.
How to make that it will be ony one instance of that Thread?

When Thread is closing? If I close service where I made it, it will be also closed?

Comment: the thread is closing when it exit from its run method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a lock or a static variable:

```
private static boolean isThreadRunning;
```

and then in your service:

```
if(isThreadRunning)
   return;

Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){

protected void run(){
   isThreadRunning=true;
   while(yourcondition){
     //your thread code...
   }
   isThreadRunning=false;
   //if you want to start another thread after this one is ended, you should post a message to a handler here and it should start another thread like this
}

});
```

Comment: But I have

run(){
infinity loop
}

And I dont know when it is ended.
If it is ended I want a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using `Handler` class, which is recommended by Google in thread operations. The code bellow shows generic example how to use it in `Service`.

```
public class MyService extends Service{


    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private final static int RUNABLE_WHAT=6558057;
    private final static int PEROID=6*1000;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(!handler.hasMessages(RUNABLE_WHAT))
        {
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(new Worker().extractMessage(), PEROID);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //DO WORK HERE
            handler.sendMessageDelayed(new Worker().extractMessage(), PEROID);
        }
        private Message extractMessage()
        {
            Message message = Message.obtain(handler, this);
            message.what=RUNABLE_WHAT;
            return message;
        }
    }


}
```